# identify data race condition in golang

Tags: go, race-condition

```
type setgetRequestInfo struct {
  mu                 sync.Mutex
  once               *sync.Once
  firstSetOccurrence time.Time
  lastSetOccurrence  time.Time
  countPerClientSet  uint64 //if it exceeds max value,it will wrap around to 0
  countPerClientGet  uint64
  cumulativeTime     time.Duration
  setType            string
}

var (
  globalSetCount, globalGetCount uint64 = 0, 0
  backendSetGetInfomap                  = &sync.Map{}
)  

func processSetRequestStatsInfo(key string, setType string, incomingSetReqTime time.Time) {
    val, loaded := backendSetGetInfomap.LoadOrStore(key, &setgetRequestInfo{setType: setType, once: &sync.Once{}})

    if !loaded {
        info := val.(*setgetRequestInfo)
        info.once.Do(func() {
           if info.countPerClientSet == 0 {
              info.firstSetOccurrence = incomingSetReqTime
           }
        })
    }
    if info, ok := val.(*setgetRequestInfo); ok {
        info.updateStats(incomingSetReqTime)
    }
}

func (info *setgetRequestInfo) updateStats(incomingSetReqTime time.Time) {
   info.mu.Lock()
   defer info.mu.Unlock()
   info.countPerClientSet++
   info.lastSetOccurrence = incomingSetReqTime
   info.cumulativeTime += time.Since(incomingSetReqTime)
}
```

i Need to verify if 2 or more goroutines will cause data race when calling processSetRequestStatsInfo
can anyone tell me how to verify ?

Comment: first question is  -- > Is there any chance 2 or more requests start processing processSetRequestStatsInfo for the same key  ?

Comment: [1/2] I do think there's a possibility for a data race. Suppose multiple clients call your method with the same key. It's guaranteed only one (any) of them causes the creation of a map entry while the rest gets the created one. Now consider that `if !loaded` guarantees that only a single client of the considered set will ever pass this condition, and that's the client who's happened to create the entry. IOW, the usage of `sync.Once` appears to be superficial as no one else is going to ever call it. But I digress.

Comment: [2/2]  While the code called by `sync.Once.Do` runs, the rest of the clients call `updateStats` concurrently–both between themselves and with that `sync.Once.Do` call, and since the code in the initialization callback does not take the same mutex as the code in `updateStats` does, there's a possibility for a time window in which the initialization callback and the updating code (holding a mutex) mutate and read the same two variables.

Comment: If I were you I'd drop the `sync.Once`, use `val, _ := backendSetGetInfomap.LoadOrStore(key, &setgetRequestInfo{setType: setType, firstSetOccurrence: incomingSetReqTime)` and leave the rest (updating) as is. This code would perform one allocation and two assignments in vain for each call not leading to a creation of a new entry, but they appear to be cheap. If you still want to go with explicit initialization, drop `sync.Once`, take the mutex in the initialization code and remove `if countPerClientSet ...` from it–just initialize the `firstSetOccurrence` field.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a data race reported. Here how I checked for it:

1. Write a test for the function that executes it in parallel for a few seconds.

```golang
func Test_processSetRequestStatsInfo(t *testing.T) {
    const routines = 100
    const testDuration = 5 * time.Second

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), testDuration)
    defer cancel()

    for i := 0; i < routines; i++ {
        go func() {
            for {
                select {
                case <-ctx.Done():
                    return
                default:
                }

                processSetRequestStatsInfo("key1", "someType", time.Now())
            }
        }()
    }
    <-ctx.Done()
}
```

The test can be improved by using different keys and types if needed.

2. Run the test with the race detector enabled:

```bash
go test -race . -count=1
```

The `-count=1` makes sure the test is run every time and cached results are ignored.

---

This will (maybe not the first time but on repeated runs) report a data race. (Omitted as file and line numbers apply to my test code.) The gist of it is that the access to `info` in updateStats collides with the access to `info` in `processSetRequestStatsInfo`. One is protected with a mutex, but the other is not.

---

@kostix has already described the issue in the comments, explaining what is happening. I'd only add that the code uses 2 different mutexes and it needs to be boiled down to 1 mutex. Currently it uses `mu` and `once` mutexes. `sync.Once` contains a mutex as well. Replacing the sync.Once with a lock to the `mu` mutex solves the issue.

```golang
type setgetRequestInfo struct {
    mu                 sync.Mutex
    firstSetOccurrence time.Time
    lastSetOccurrence  time.Time
    countPerClientSet  uint64 // if it exceeds max value,it will wrap around to 0
    countPerClientGet  uint64
    cumulativeTime     time.Duration
    setType            string
}

var (
    globalSetCount, globalGetCount uint64 = 0, 0
    backendSetGetInfomap                  = &sync.Map{}
)

func processSetRequestStatsInfo(key string, setType string, incomingSetReqTime time.Time) {
    val, loaded := backendSetGetInfomap.LoadOrStore(key, &setgetRequestInfo{setType: setType})

    if !loaded {
        info := val.(*setgetRequestInfo)
        info.mu.Lock()
        if info.countPerClientSet == 0 {
            info.firstSetOccurrence = incomingSetReqTime
        }
        info.mu.Unlock()
    }
    if info, ok := val.(*setgetRequestInfo); ok {
        info.updateStats(incomingSetReqTime)
    }
}

func (info *setgetRequestInfo) updateStats(incomingSetReqTime time.Time) {
    info.mu.Lock()
    defer info.mu.Unlock()
    info.countPerClientSet++
    info.lastSetOccurrence = incomingSetReqTime
    info.cumulativeTime += time.Since(incomingSetReqTime)
}
```

Comment: A minor nitpick: all subcommands of `go` take single-dash options, like `-run` and `-count`; I do not think lax parsing of double-dashed ones is guaranteed to not be broken in the future. So better not use them–at least for public demonstration purposes ;-)

Comment: @kostix The Go tools use the [flag](https://godoc.org/flag) package to parse command line arguments. The flag package documentation explicitly states that double dashes are permitted.